# How do I search for a string and return that string from an email in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I can extract the body of an email but I can not find a way to search that body. findText only works on documents and I haven't found a way to put an email into a document. The search in email only returns the whole email, which I already have. Am I looking at this the wrong way or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can get the body of the email as a string, here is something you could try:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

// Use editAsText to obtain a single text element containing
// all the characters in the document.
var text = doc.editAsText();

// Insert text at the beginning of the document.
text.insertText(0, 'Your Text To Insert.\n');

//Find search for your results
text.findText(searchPattern)
```

I am not familiar with Google-Script but I hope this could possibly point you in the right direction.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_text

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, if this is the way to go, I haven't found a way to insert my text into a document. My text is the body of an email message which I have in the variable message_body, but I can't find a way to get that into a document.

Comment: @user1931379 What are you able to get? Do you get the body of the email back as a string?

Comment: @user1931379 Also you could create a new document and then add the text to it, I think that's what I was trying to do in the above answer, but I see now I'm loading a previous document instead of creating a new one. I'll update my answer in a little to show how.

Comment: Cheers, yes I think I had no previous document so I couldn't get one, so I tried creating one and then I could insert the message body and use findText to search for a string. Now my problem have become, how do I get, use, display etc my search results? I have the int's of start and finish but how do I use them? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I think I just found an answer search_result.getElement().getText(), a few more characters than the string I was expecting but progress none the less. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will get the whole element, how do I just get the text I am searching for?

Comment: @user1931379 Can you give an example of what you are trying to get? Is it like you have a string "Hello world, this is a test string." and you are trying to search for a get back only "Hello world"? or is it that you just need to get the text that is embedded in the element?